# Test on mobile devices using xammp and virtual hosts

Tags: localhost

Using xxamp for local development, I used to be able to put my ip address into my phone to test websites as long as they were on the same wifi network.

I've since set up virtual hosts so that I can build multiple websites without having to keep changing the configuration file.

I can't work out though what I need to put into my phone. So on my local dev machiine I go to

MYSITE.localhost on the mobile it feels like it should be MYSITE.192.*whatever* but it won't work. My virtual host settings are

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    DocumentRoot "/PATHTOWEBSITE/"
    ServerName MYSITE.localhost
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host2.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas? Sorry I haven't been using xxamp for long so might be asking the question in the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP Proxy Settings on Devices.

Go to your Wi-Fi settings on devices and look for HTTP PROXY. Enter your IP address and Port or whatever you have used.

Then you should be able to view your virtual host on devices. :)

Answer (score 0):

I work with MAMP, but it's pretty much the same I guess.

1. You should know your network IP (look for it in network settings/preferences)
2. Your devices should be on a same network.
3. In your htpd-vhosts.conf change your virtual host port to unique one if you have more than one vh on the same port [for example, I have two:  &  ]
4. Start your server on with the port of your project
5. On your device surf to IP:port [for example: 10.68.68.110:80] and that's it